# AddEventListener for window.matchMedia is not working javascript

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design, responsive

I am using window.matchMedia().When I change the size of the window,I want the function getSlidesCount() to be invoked. Please help me find the error.

```
var max_slides=4,max_items=3;
var screen_size = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)");
 function getSlidesCount(){
     console.log(window.innerWidth);
 if (screen_size.matches) { // If media query matches
    max_slides=4;
    max_items=3; 
  } else {
   max_slides=2;
   max_items=6;
  }
}
getSlidesCount();
screen_size.addEventListener("resize",getSlidesCount);
```

So as you can see in the first image the window is full screen. At that time the function getSlidesCount() is invoked and 1336 is printed in the console.

In the second image the browser iis resized but the function getSlidesCount() is not getting invoked and nothing is printed in the console.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: I am trying to understand your problem here so correct me if I am wrong. You want to call `getSlidesCount()` if the screen size is less than 600px, is it correct?

Comment: Hey.Thank you for replying. I want to invoke getSlidesCount() once when the script is loaded and again if the size of the window is changed.

Comment: Hey I uploaded some images please look to them

Comment: so you want to load this `getSlidesCount()` function once after the page loads?

Comment: I want to run the getSlidesCount() function whenever I resize the browser window

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pma9vfyw/3/. the function  onScreen_resize() is called whenever the browser window is resized.

Comment: Thank u so much! So the mistake was I wrote "screen_size.addEventListener("resize",getSlidesCount);" insted of "window.addEventListener("resize",getSlidesCount);"

Comment: @Rounin is right, and please mark his solution as your answer.

Comment: No worries @Rounin.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to listen for changes to the size of the viewport, then you will need:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', getSlidesCount);
```

And if you want to log to the console the width of the viewport, then you will need:

```
console.log(window.innerWidth);
```

---

**Working Example:**

```js
let max_slides = 4;
let max_items = 3;
const screen_size = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)");

function getSlidesCount () {

  console.log(window.innerWidth);
 
  if (screen_size.matches) { // If media query matches
    max_slides = 4;
    max_items = 3;
    console.log('Media query matches screen_size query');
  } else {
    max_slides = 2;
    max_items = 6;
    console.log('Media query does not match screen_size query');
  }
}

getSlidesCount();
window.addEventListener('resize', getSlidesCount);
```

Comment: The function getSlidesCount() is not getting invoked when the size of the window is changed.

Comment: If the code is operating within an iframe, the iframe is the viewport. Otherwise the browser viewport is the viewport.